# google route peering as nexthop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, vpc-peering, google-cloud-vpn

Using the google cloud web interface for add a custom route with a peering as nexthop,But in this interface and in gcloud too, we can select only as next hop:

```
--next-hop-address=NEXT_HOP_ADDRESS
--next-hop-gateway=NEXT_HOP_GATEWAY
--next-hop-ilb=NEXT_HOP_ILB
--next-hop-instance=NEXT_HOP_INSTANCE
--next-hop-vpn-tunnel=NEXT_HOP_VPN_TUNNEL)
--next-hop-ilb-region=NEXT_HOP_ILB_REGION]
--next-hop-instance-zone=NEXT_HOP_INSTANCE_ZONE]
--next-hop-vpn-tunnel-region=NEXT_HOP_VPN_TUNNEL_REGION
```

But if you do a vpc peering with automatic import and export routes, google cloud create ruotes using the peering as follow:

peering-route-c1c2eo5fcx1dfd1b  my-vpc  10.0.1.0/27   vpc-peering                          1000

My question is: is there anyway to create a custom route using the peering as nexthop?

Because event from google api the option exists:

```
NextHopPeering
```

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/compute/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Compute_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Route.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently that feature is not available, however there is a feature request already created.

I share you the   [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/149812699)  to the public issue tracker. I suggest to star it and comment it so google can know that there are more customers requesting this feature.

Comment: Thanks, for the information :)